# Java cutting string pairs

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hashmap

So here I have a string from 3200 characters I have to find the pair with most space between them I already have the code to find the pair, but then I have to remove the first char of the pair and move the second at the end of the string and do this things till it's not possible to so. Here is what I've done so far

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringPairs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = readInputString();
        printIdenticalSymbols(inputString);
    }

    private static String readInputString() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = in.nextLine();
        in.close();
        return inputString;
    }


    private static void printIdenticalSymbols(String inputString) {
        Map<Character, Integer> symbolsMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        char longestChar = ' ';
        int longestDiff = -1;
        int firstIndex = -1;
        int lastIndex = -1;
        int firstOccurenceOfLastIdentical = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            char currentCharacter = inputString.charAt(i);
            if (!symbolsMap.containsKey(currentCharacter)) {
                symbolsMap.put(currentCharacter, i);
                continue;
            }

            int firstOccurenceIndex = symbolsMap.get(currentCharacter);
            if (firstOccurenceIndex < firstOccurenceOfLastIdentical) {
                symbolsMap.put(currentCharacter, i);
                continue;
            }

            int currentIdenticalLength = i - firstOccurenceIndex;
            if (currentIdenticalLength > longestDiff) {
                longestChar = currentCharacter;
                longestDiff = currentIdenticalLength;
                firstIndex = firstOccurenceIndex;
                lastIndex = i;
            } 

            firstOccurenceOfLastIdentical = firstOccurenceIndex;
            symbolsMap.put(currentCharacter, i);

        }
        System.out.println(longestChar + " - " + firstIndex + ":" + lastIndex);
    }
}
```

example input:

```
brtba
```

output: b:space between them(it already does this) and rtab if the string is bigger do this thing till it's not possible to do so.

Comment: Please show us sample input and expected output.

Comment: @TheLostMind Done edit added

Answer (score 0):

It suspiciously looks like homework to me.

Anyway, you should look into String manipulation functions, especially String.substring(begin,end).  To make a loop, look into the while loop.  Note that you don't handle yet the case where there is no pair.

This being said, I don't understand the function of the test:
    (firstOccurenceIndex < firstOccurenceOfLastIdentical).